# How to alert something into another iFrame

Tags: java, dhtml

I have created an iFrame containing albums using DHTML. When I click on the individual album I want to then have the individual songs of the individual album listed in the iFrame next to it. How do I alert the individual album songs into the next iFrame using DHTML?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the  elements are served from the same domain, then they can access each other directly. For example, in iframe1 you could do:

```
var someDiv = top.document.getElementById('otherIframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('someOtherDiv').innerHTML;
```